# Node sql syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, syntax

I'm a little new to using node and express and I'm trying to do a simple insert into mysql database in my node app, but I keep getting getting an ER_PARSE_ERROR `[i].year, courseData[i].term`....

I'm trying to just look over an array of course objects (courseData) inserting each value into their column names. Here is where I'm at

```
for (var i = 0; i < courseData.length; i++){
        var i = 1;
        let sql = "INSERT INTO Course (year, term, code, title, " 
                    + "capacity, enrollment, credits, "
                    + "mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, " 
                    + "instructorLast, instructorFirst, " 
                    + "startDate, endDate, building, room) "
                   + "VALUES (courseData[i].year, courseData[i].term, courseData[i].code, "
                    + "courseData[i].title, courseData[i].capacity, courseData[i].enrollment, "
                    + "courseData[i].credits, courseData[i].mon, courseData[i].tue, "
                    + "courseData[i].wed, courseData[i].thu, courseData[i].fri "
                    + "courseData[i].sat, courseData[i].instructorLast, courseData[i].instructorFirst, "
                    + "courseData[i].startDate, courseData[i].endDate, courseData[i].building, courseData[i].room); ";

        db.query(sql, function(err, result, fields){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

I have tried single quotes, double quotes, back ticks around my table name but nothing worked. Didn't see any similar questions so I thought I would try my luck.

Thank you!

Comment: `year` is a MySQL reserved word.  You'll need to escape that column with backticks anywhere you use it.

Comment: Ah didn't know that. Would probably just be easier to change my column name no?

Comment: It will be a lot easier in the long run for sure.  `dYear` is my go-to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two things to fix this code.

1) Aaron Dietz is correct. You need backticks on the year column

2) Currently your inserting the string value of your objectname instead of your object. For example, your inserting "courseData[i].title" instead of the acutal content of that part of the object. Also, concatenating sql code is subject to sql injection attacks. Use the escaping methods as described here https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql.

```
for (var i = 0; i < courseData.length; i++){
    var i = 1;
    let sql = `INSERT INTO Course (dyear, term, code, title,
                capacity, enrollment, credits,
                mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat,
               instructorLast, instructorFirst,
                startDate, endDate, building, room)
               VALUES (?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
               ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`;
    let inserts = [courseData[i].year, courseData[i].term, 
              courseData[i].code, courseData[i].title, 
              courseData[i].capacity, courseData[i].enrollment, 
              courseData[i].credits, courseData[i].mon, 
              courseData[i].tue, courseData[i].wed, 
              courseData[i].thu, courseData[i].fri, 
              courseData[i].sat, courseData[i].instructorLast, 
              courseData[i].instructorFirst, courseData[i].startDate, 
              courseData[i].endDate, courseData[i].building, 
              courseData[i].room];
    sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

    db.query(sql, function(err, result, fields){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You are right...I just assumed the double quotes would interpret my syntax. But now I have a different problem...some of my values like title and code have spaces in them and its throwing errors. I tried this
("courseData[i].title")
but its still just printing the string literal.

Comment: You need backticks for those as well in MySQL right? (I'm more of a SQL Server guy) So you need to incorporate the backticks in the string part without changing the variables that you are taking from the JavaScript object. See updated answer.

Comment: **Warning** this code is vulnerable to **SQL injection attacks**. Do NOT concatenate values in your SQL query, use parameterized queries.

Comment: You are correct. Was too much focused on the original problem. Updating answer now.

Comment: @jcaron you are right, but this is basically throw away code, I only need to get the data inserted and I won't need to do this again.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Abbasi bad habits die hard. It’s by far the most common vulnerability, the most used attack vector, despite being the easiest to fix. Throwaway code DOES get reused, and answers on SO even more so. Thanks to Imre_G for the fix.

Comment: @jcaron indeed, I am going to be focusing on preventing SQL injection on different parts of my app. Thank you for you response!