# NodeJS / MySQL quotes in query data url

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, quotes, double-quotes

Heey all, I have a quick question concerning simple/double quotes in javascript, using NodeJS and MySQL database.. here's my code

```js
app.get('/AddCollection', function (req, res) {
  var queryData = url.parse(req.url , true).query;
    connection.query("INSERT IGNORE INTO collections VALUES ('" +queryData.nom+ "' ,'"  +queryData.categorie+ "','" +queryData.description+ "','" + queryData.urlimage+"')", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json("Vous avez ajouté "+queryData.categorie+"et"+queryData.description+"et"+queryData.objet+"a la table");
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

delete query :

```js
app.get('/DeleteCollection', function (req, res) {
  var queryData = url.parse(req.url , true).query;
    connection.query("DELETE FROM `collections` WHERE `collections`.`nom` ='"+queryData.nom+"'", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json("Vous avez ajouté supprimé la collection"+ queryData.nom);
        }
    );
});
```

Thing is that I already used simple and double quotes for the call. 
**So for example, if queryData.nom or queryData.categorie is equal to `the heroes' places` then the code won't work as it will confuse the simple quotes..
How do I fix that?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node sql syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442567/node-sql-syntax-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single quote escape in JavaScript function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744315/single-quote-escape-in-javascript-function-parameters)

Comment: yeah I've read these threads but didn't manage to make it work =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterize your query

```
connection.query("INSERT IGNORE INTO collections VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [queryData.nom, queryData.categorie, queryData.description, queryData.urlimage], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json("Vous avez ajouté "+queryData.categorie+"et"+queryData.description+"et"+queryData.objet+"a la table");
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks loads man! do you know how I would do that with a delete query?
i've Updated the answer and added the delete one, i've searched a bit but it seems so weird..

Comment: connection.query("DELETE FROM `collections` WHERE `collections`.`nom` = ?", [queryData.nom], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json("Vous avez ajouté supprimé la collection"+ queryData.nom);
        }
    );